Build list of widgets from asynchronous call
I need to make a dynamic list of Widgets
Then I created a function that returns a list of widgets
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
    child: SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
        child: Column(
          children: getRandomWidgetArray(),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

List<Widget> getRandomWidgetArray() {
  List<Widget> widgets = [];

  for (int i = 0; i \< 5; i++) {
    widgets.add(
      TextFormField(
        decoration: const InputDecoration(
          labelText: 'DEP',
          labelStyle: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.black,
            fontSize: 12,
            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
          ),
          fillColor: Colors.black12,
          filled: true,
          border: OutlineInputBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(
              Radius.circular(4),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  return widgets;
}


In this format it returns the data I need
But if I put a function to fetch the data from the fields in the database, it returns an error.
_TypeError (type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>')

This is how I'm retrieving the information from my database:
getEnsaioItem(String ens_codigo, String ens_estaca) async {

  try {
    final Database db = await _getDatabase();

    List ensaioItem = [];
    
    ensaioItem = await db.rawQuery(
          "SELECT * FROM ensaioitem  WHERE ens_codigo = ? AND ens_ite_estaca = ? ORDER BY ens_ite_ordem ASC",
          [ens_codigo, ens_estaca]);
    
    return ensaioItem.toList();
      
    } catch (ex) {
      return List.empty();
    }

}

And this is the function that should fetch the data:
List<Widget> getRandomWidgetArray() {
  List itemEnsaio = [];
  itemEnsaio = EnsaioItemDatasource().getEnsaioItem('210', '1');
  for (int i = 0; i < itemEnsaio.length; i++) {
    print(itemEnsaio[i]['ens_codigo']);
  }
}


The major issue that you're seeing here is related to asynchronous programming in dart. The first step I would take if I were you would be to make sure that the return type of your functions are set, which would give you a better idea of what's going on.
The getEnsaioItem function you have declared is asynchronous, and so must be returning a Future. Since you have a return statement with a List<?> in the function, the return type must be of type Future<List<?>>. I'm using the ? to represent the fact that I'm not sure what exactly the type of the list is - that's something you should ensure is handled in the code.
Now, in the getRandomWidgetArray function, you aren't actually building out the list. I'm assuming that might be an oversight when you copied in the code, but either way you should make sure you're actually creating widgets and adding them to the list before returning.
However, because this function is calling the asynchronous getEnsaioItem function, it must also be asynchronous - otherwise it won't have time to retrieve the items from your database. It should have a return type Future<List<Widget>>, or a more specific Widget subclass.
Once you've corrected those issues, there is the problem of how you're going to actually do this in your code. There's two main ways that you could go about this without bringing any more complicated state management.

Use a FutureBuilder. The documentation does a good job of explaining how to use it.
Use a stateful widget and setState

In either of these cases, you're probably going to want to change your widget to a StatefulWidget, and initialize the future in the initState or when the widget's state is built. If you use a FutureBuilder, you then just need to pass the future to it and make sure you handle the case where the future has not completed yet. If you just use a StatefulWidget, you're probably going to want to initialize an empty list when the widget is created, then setState the list to the list you're returning from your function once it has completed.
There's a dart codelab which goes into detail how asynchronous programming works and would probably be a good read, although it doesn't necessarily do a good job of informing you how that relates to flutter.
